# Redirect all EE-URLs to one

Tags: url, redirects

I have three URLs for every entry:

1 https://www.xy.de/site/single/zahnraeder-zeichnen-aufgaben

2 https://www.xy.de/site/single/zahnraeder-zeichnen-aufgaben/3093

3 https://www.xy.de/site/single/3093

Is there any way to redirect them to 1 ?
I would prefer to kill 2 and 3 permanently, but I don't know how to do this technically.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

you'll want to use 301 redirects in your `.htaccess` file

e.g:

```
Redirect 301 /site/single/zahnraeder-zeichnen-aufgaben/3093 /site/single/zahnraeder-zeichnen-aufgaben
Redirect 301 /site/single/3093 /site/single/zahnraeder-zeichnen-aufgaben
```

(pay attention to the spaces)

and something like this should be at the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://www.xy.de%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I would have to do this for every single entry. I have a lot of entries which all have to be directed, so I need a dynamic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Are all of those entries using the same template?

If so I would setup a template route in the CP. Something like:

`/site/single/{title:alpha_dash}`

And in your template route make sure you require segments.

In your template I would use `url_title="{segment_3}"` in your `exp:channel:entries` loop and add:

```
{if no_results}
    {redirect="404"}
{/if}
```

Additionally, consider adding the following to your template (in your entries loop) if the above doesn't cover it.

```
{if segment_4}
    {redirect="/site/single/{url_title}"}
{/if}
```